# Flutter how to convert a csv list to a map?

Tags: flutter, csv, dictionary

I am using this to retrieve a map from json:

```
class ProdutosApi {
  static Future<List<Produto>> getProdutos(BuildContext context) async {
    final assetBundle = DefaultAssetBundle.of(context);
    final data = await assetBundle.loadString('assets/produtos.json');
    final body = json.decode(data);
    return body.map<Produto>(Produto.fromJson).toList();
  }
}
```

How can I do the same, but loading from CSV?

```
class AplicacaoHelper {

  Future<List> getAllAplicacoes() async {
    final arquivo = new File('data/produtos.csv').openRead();
    final csv = await arquivo.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(
        new CsvToListConverter(fieldDelimiter: ';')).toList();

    ??????????
}
```

Thanks in advance!

I have tried that:

```
static Future<List<Aplicacao>> getAplicacoes(BuildContext context) async {

    final arquivo = File('assets/produtos.csv').openRead();
    var csv = await arquivo
      .transform(utf8.decoder)
      .transform(CsvToListConverter(fieldDelimiter: ';'))
      .toList();

    return csv.map<Aplicacao>(Aplicacao.fromJson);
  }
```

Comment: Is the String inside the ';' of the csv the same used to represent a product in json? eg("{"name":"product"}")

Comment: Yes.   static Aplicacao fromJson(json) =>
      Aplicacao(
        id: json['id'],
        descricao: json['descricao'],
      );

Comment: `CsvToListConverter(fieldDelimiter: ';')),map((e)=> Aplicacao.fromJson(e)).toList()`